# Get permutations of ordered sets of N values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that consists of a set codes for an item. Each code's group is defined by `group_id`. The table is defined as follows:

```sql
CREATE TABLE item_code (
  id int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL IDENTITY (1,1),
  item_id int DEFAULT NULL,
  group_id int NOT NULL,
  code varchar(50) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE groups (
  id int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL IDENTITY (1,1),
  name varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  order int NOT NULL
)
```

For each `item_id` in the table, I need to select 1 `code` from each `group_id` ordered by the group's `order`. For example:

```sql
INSERT INTO groups (id, name, order) VALUES (1, 'one', 10), (2, 'two', 20), (3, 'three', 30);

INSERT INTO item_code (item_id, group_id, [code])
VALUES
    (99, 1, 'code1-1'),
    (99, 1, 'code1-2'),
    (99, 2, 'code2-1'),
    (99, 2, 'code2-2'),
    (99, 3, 'code3-1'),
    (100,1, 'another-code');
```

would result in the set:

```
item_id code_combination 
     99   "code1-1"
     99   "code1-2"
     99   "code2-1"
     99   "code2-2"
     99   "code3-1"
     99   "code1-1, code2-1"
     99   "code1-1, code2-2"
     99   "code1-2, code2-1"
     99   "code1-2, code2-2"
     99   "code1-1, code3-1"
     99   "code1-2, code3-1"
     99   "code2-1, code3-1"
     99   "code2-2, code3-1"
     99   "code1-1, code2-1, code3-1"
     99   "code1-2, code2-1, code3-1"
     99   "code1-1, code2-2, code3-1"
     99   "code1-2, code2-2, code3-1"
     100  "another-code"
```

The order of the actual results does not matter. I included a row for `item_id` == 100 just to show that results for all item_id should be included.

**What I've done so far:**
I've build a CTE that gets combinations of codes, but it does not respect item_id, groups or order and that's where I'm stuck:

```
;WITH cte ( combination, curr ) AS (
  SELECT CAST(ic.code AS VARCHAR(MAX)), ic.id
  FROM   items_code ic
  UNION ALL
  SELECT CAST( c.combination + ',' + CAST(ic.code AS VARCHAR(10) ) AS VARCHAR(MAX) ), ic.id
  FROM   item_code ic
         INNER JOIN
         cte c
         ON ( c.curr < ic.id )
)
SELECT combination FROM cte
```

**UPDATE:** I have a slightly more complicated schema than what I originally posted, and have built the schema in [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8e52d/4/0). The idea is the same, it's just that "order" is defined on a different table.

Comment: I don't understand what you are getting at, but you don't have a FK reference for the table, and you are using the identity property on the group table which will unlikely match the item table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a little more to your recursive cte, expanding the final join conditions, as well as some additional columns:

```
;with cte as (
  select
      ic.id
    , ic.item_id
    , ic.group_id
    , g.[order]
    , level = 0
    , combination = cast(ic.code as varchar(max))
  from item_code ic
    inner join groups g
      on ic.group_id = g.id
  union all
  select 
      ic.id
    , ic.item_id
    , ic.group_id
    , g.[order]
    , level = c.level + 1
    , combination = cast( c.combination + ',' + cast(ic.code as varchar(10) ) as varchar(max) )
  from item_code ic
    inner join groups g
      on ic.group_id = g.id
    inner join cte c
      on c.id < ic.id 
     and c.[order] < g.[order]
     and c.item_id = ic.item_id
)
select * 
from cte
order by item_id, level, combination
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/PJC44281

returns:

```
+----+---------+----------+-------+-------+-------------------------+
| id | item_id | group_id | order | level |       combination       |
+----+---------+----------+-------+-------+-------------------------+
|  1 |      99 |        1 |    10 |     0 | code1-1                 |
|  2 |      99 |        1 |    10 |     0 | code1-2                 |
|  3 |      99 |        2 |    20 |     0 | code2-1                 |
|  4 |      99 |        2 |    20 |     0 | code2-2                 |
|  5 |      99 |        3 |    30 |     0 | code3-1                 |
|  3 |      99 |        2 |    20 |     1 | code1-1,code2-1         |
|  4 |      99 |        2 |    20 |     1 | code1-1,code2-2         |
|  5 |      99 |        3 |    30 |     1 | code1-1,code3-1         |
|  3 |      99 |        2 |    20 |     1 | code1-2,code2-1         |
|  4 |      99 |        2 |    20 |     1 | code1-2,code2-2         |
|  5 |      99 |        3 |    30 |     1 | code1-2,code3-1         |
|  5 |      99 |        3 |    30 |     1 | code2-1,code3-1         |
|  5 |      99 |        3 |    30 |     1 | code2-2,code3-1         |
|  5 |      99 |        3 |    30 |     2 | code1-1,code2-1,code3-1 |
|  5 |      99 |        3 |    30 |     2 | code1-1,code2-2,code3-1 |
|  5 |      99 |        3 |    30 |     2 | code1-2,code2-1,code3-1 |
|  5 |      99 |        3 |    30 |     2 | code1-2,code2-2,code3-1 |
|  6 |     100 |        1 |    10 |     0 | another-code            |
+----+---------+----------+-------+-------+-------------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. When I first wrote this question, I tried to simplify my schema, but I may have done myself a disservice because I'm having difficulty translating your answer to my real schema. If you wouldn't mind looking, I've created a SQLFiddle that shows the real schema...it seems to be mixing codes across products and also within groups:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8e52d/4/0

Comment: Not quite. I've modified the constraints of the join to `item_group`, and I'm getting closer. But I can't seem to get anything past "level 1", that is, a 3 code combination. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8e52d/16/0

Comment: @Thelonias [sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8e52d/25](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8e52d/25) I think this is what you are looking for. Let me know.

Comment: It seems so close, but notice how there are multiple codes from the same group in a combination (e.g. lw_15, lw_16). This is an invalid combination. There are also combinations that do not exist in the results (e.g. 17, lw_15, a).

Comment: @Thelonias ([lego batman](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=44-RsrF_V_w)) First try! http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8e52d/36 -- fixed the same group error, and has the permutation you said was missing (as well as those of the like).

Comment: Now we're talking! This looks good, and I'm going to mark it as the answer. If you're feeling up to it, there's one additional constraint that I want to try and factor in. Notice the `required` field in `item_group`? I want to make it so that if a group is required, there MUST be a code from that group in each combination result. For example, if "group_one" is required, "17", "21", or "25" MUST be in the result. This is essentially a filter of the results we're getting now.

Comment: @Thelonias for `required` filter:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/4a500/1 -- I chose `group_two` for required because it shows that the filter works for middle groups vs. a false positive you can get by using `group_one` and just adding `where ig.required=1` to the first (parent) query in the `cte`.